Python type hinting, input type depends on the output type of another function
Consider the following functions
def f1(a:int, b:int):
    return (a,b)

def f2(x):
    a, b = x
    return a

How do I hint that the type hinting of argument 'x' of 'f2' is the type of output of 'f1', i.e. 'tuple[int,int]', automatically.
I currently use the following naive code, so that I can know that the output type of 'f2' is 'int'
from typing import Tuple

def f1(a:int, b:int):
    return (a,b)

def f2(x:Tuple[int,int]):
    a, b = x
    return a

However, when I modify 'f1', I have to also modify 'f2'.
For example, If I want to change 'f1' to
def f1(a:int, b:str):
    return (a,b)

I have to also change 'f2' to
def f2(x:Tuple[int,str]):
    a, b = x
    return a

Is there a more convenient way to do this? just like the following
def f1(a:int, b:int):
    return (a,b)

def f2(x:output_type_of[f1]):
    return x[1]


do you need to use type hints? and is it sufficient to just use *args?

You can use a type alias (named F1Result, for example) to annotate both the return type of f1 and the argument type of f2.
from typing import Tuple

F1Result = Tuple[int, int]

def f1(a: int, b: int) -> F1Result:
    return (a, b)

def f2(x: F1Result) -> int:
    return x[1]


Thank you for your answer, but I think this is not what I wanted. I just edited the problem   body to explain more clearly.

@jingbin this is a canonical way to do this in python type system. There is nothing like output_type_of. Your edits don't seem to invalidate this answer in any way - if you change the type, you only do it in one place, updating alias definition.

(to make this crystal clear: in all your examples f1 output is untyped and so defaults to Any. If you see it inferred as some tuple, it's your IDE tricking, not the typechecker - PEP484 is explicit about this)

You can explictly specify all the types of outputs it can possibly give like in this answer and use the same as possible inputs for f2. While this doesn't connect the two it is sufficient if the reader can see that f1's returns are inputs of f2.
Another option is using a User-defined generic types like this
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def f1(a: int, b: int) -> Tuple[T, T]:
    return (a, b)

def f2(x: Tuple[T, T]) -> None:  
    return x[1]


You can read more on this here
